# Reverse 2d array vertically?

Tags: c++

Okay, I got the filling of the 2D array pretty well... now I need to keep the same values that are randomly generated into the 2D array, but reverse the order of the vertical (the 2nd for loop). So basically the 2nd for loop needs to keep the same values, but in reverse order.
But I feel like if I go into the nested for loops and rand(), it will generate all new random letters...

Does anyone know how to go about doing this??
This is what I have so far:

```
char array[20][20];

srand(time(NULL));

for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
 {
     for(int j=0;j<20;j++) {
         array[i][j]= ((rand() % 2) == 0) ? 'O' : 'X';
         cout << array[i][j];
     }
     cout << endl;

     for(int j=20-1; i>=0; i-- {
         array[i][j]= ((rand() % 2) == 0) ? 'O' : 'X';
         cout << array[j][i];
     }
     cout << endl;
 }
```

EDIT
For anyone who is curious on how to fix this, I figured it out!!
Here is the code:

```
char array[20][20];

srand(time(NULL));

for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
     for(int j=0;j<20;j++) {
         array[i][j]= ((rand() % 2) == 0) ? 'O' : 'X';
         cout << array[i][j];
     }
     cout << endl;
}

cout << endl;

for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
    for(int j=19;j>=0;j--) {
        cout << array[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You this condition doesn't look good:

```
  `for(int j=20-1; i>=0; i-- {`
```

**as its altering out loop index variable back to `0`, which will make the the our loop run indefinite.**

Also I don't think you need to assign new values inside the second loop (you want to retain the values from first loop)

Instead it should be as(**outside the current loop**):

```
  for(int i=19;i>=0;i--)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<20;j++) {
       //no need of line below as you want to print the old values
       //array[i][j]= ((rand() % 2) == 0) ? 'O' : 'X'; 
       cout << array[i][j];
     }
  }
```

This way it will print the bottom row first with columns unchanged.

Comment: Do I keep that in the same place?? Because it's not printing right. It's mixing it in with the other array since it's going through the outer loop and then doing BOTHER for loops in the outer loop and they're smashing in together...

Comment: @Peanut: I see. If you keep in the same loop then it will not print the right values as your array is not fully assigned. Move it outside. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yes I pasted what you have right there.. It just prints the same exact grid. I feel like you're answer is so close. I've been modifying it like crazy. I dont see why it's printing the same grid when the first for loop is... going in reverse :/

Comment: GOT IT WORKING!
for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
  for(int j=19;j>=0;j--) {
   cout << array[i][j];
  }
  cout << endl;
 }

Comment: @Peanut: Good. I left the index thing as before :( (typo error) Updated it. I moved out so culdn't see your last comment earlier. If you think, it was helpful, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: @Peanut: for(int i=0;i<20;i++) { for(int j=19;j>=0;j--) { cout << array[i][j]; } cout << endl; }  will reverse horizontally. I mean last column as first column and first column as last column. If this is what you want then its fine otherwise use the one in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of swapping up all of the elements in your reversal with nested for-loops, you can just do 1 for loop as follows:

- Swap `array[0]` with `array[19]`
- Swap `array[1]` with `array[18]`
- ... and so on

Pseudo code:

```
int i;
int size = 20;
int bound = size / 2;
for(i = 0; i < bound; i++) {
     swap(array[i], array[bound-i]);
}
```

The reason being that `array[i]` is a pointer to that particular row. So you can get away with swapping the pointers without touching the values.

Comment: Where would I put that in my code? I don't understand how I would start switching up the 2nd [] in the array..